# About Hecke-Bochner identity

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $f\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb R^2)$ be of the form
$$f(z)=f_1(|z|)e^{in\theta}, \quad z=|z|e^{i\theta}.$$
In a paper, I found that using the **Hecke-Bochner identity**, we get
$$\hat{f}(z)=\hat{f}(\lambda e^{i s})=\lambda^{|m|}g(\lambda)e^{ims}, $$
where $g(\lambda)$ is a constant times the $2 + 2|m|$−dimensional Fourier transform of the
function $\frac{f_1(|z|)}{|z|^{|m|}}$ considered as a radial function on $\mathbb R^{2 + 2|m|}$.

What is the statement of this theorem (Hecke-Bochner identity) and what is this theorem for?

Comment: You haven't found anything on the web ?

Comment: no no, I searched but without success

Comment: A maybe too general paper https://www.esi.ac.at/preprints/esi2416.pdf